# How to create checkstyle rule prevent specific modified clasess

Tags: git, sonarqube, push, checkstyle, rule

I want to show an alert in sonarqube if a class changes when someone makes push.

How can I alert that? I think that making a new rule on checkstyle perhaps I could do it but how can I look if the file changes?

Comment: Uhm... you want to raise an issue when a class is edited? Why not simply lock down commit permissions on the code repository?

Comment: I want the rest of my team make commit and push but there are some files that They shouldnt modify so when they touch some of this class I want to alert on gradle or sonarqube or bamboo that says 'hey you shouldnt touch that file..'

Answer (score 1):

Imagination fails on this one. I believe you're trying to use the wrong tool for the task.

If you have classes that you don't want modified as part of normal development, then your best course (IMO) would be to extract them into a separate library. Use the library as a project dependency and developers will have the same access as before to use the classes. And you can use repository permissions to control who/how/when changes are made to the classes in question..

Answer (score 0):

Nor checkstyle nor SonarQube are the right tools for this: They analyze the source of the code: They haveno knowledge of the changes on a file (SQ relies on the SCM for this).

You would be better off by using, for instance, some SCM hooks on commit to either prevent commit or send an email when a certain file is touched.
Or, as suggested by Ann: if these classes are that sensitive that would make sense to keep them in a separate project to control access and lifecycle.